# How to migrate 'local notes' or 'on my mac' notes to iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, notes.app

I've seen so many questions asked about it, and I found a proper solution today while working. See below. I searched around, and everyone's answer has been either 'copy all of your notes manually' or use a '3rd party solution'. This requires neither.

Comment: It might have been better to post the answer directly to one of the many similar questions on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

- All devices need the New Notes upgrade to be compatible with this.
- Update to New Notes on each device.
- Open folders view and select Local Notes or On My Phone.
- Tap on Edit in the upper right corner and tap on Move All in the lower left corner.
- You should see this:

iCloud

New Folder

'Notes 0 >' [or not including the local notes]

- Tap on Notes

They will empty out of the local notes folder and move into iCloud.

Again, you won't see any of these notes until you upgrade to New Notes.

Pro-Tip: This also works for migrating Gmail notes, etc.

Comment: So then this will not work on iOS9 will it?  My wife needs to do exactly this but her phone is on iOS9 and will not be updated.

Answer (score 11):

On Mac #1, I just transferred all my "Local Notes" into iCloud and can see them in Mac #2:

1. Click on "Local Notes" on left side of Notes window.
2. Hit Command+A to Select All notes.
3. With mouse, drag all selected notes into "Notes" under "iCloud" on left side of Notes window.